# iOS - Init View Controllers in Tab Bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uilabel

I'm working on a project with two tabs. On my First View Controller I'm attempting to call a method that's located in my Second View Controller. The method on the Second View Controller updates a UILabel on this Second View Controller. The problem is the Second View Controller doesn't init on launch therefore the method isn't properly called. I can use the following to manually init the Second View Controller

```
     if (secondView==nil) {
        secondView = [[SecondView alloc]init];
    }
```

and then the method is launched (tested by placing a breakpoint on said method and verified that it does trigger), but my UILabel doesn't update, which leads me to believe that the Second View Controller is initialized on a different thread.

My question is: How do I initialize the Second View controller on the same thread so that the UI will update when I click over to that tab? Is there a way to do this in the appDelegate
?

I've verified that the IBOutlet is wired to the label properly, .h file is imported properly, and method for SecondViewController is stated in the .H file.

Code is listed below:

```
FirstViewController.m

-(void)myMethod
{
     [secondView updateLabel];
}

SecondViewController.m
-(void)updateLabel
{
    myLabel.text = myString;
}
```

Comment: You should put the function in a centralized class / App Delegate, instead of calling other View Controller's methods.

Comment: So, based your comment it sounds like its not proper etiquette to call another view controller's method directly? Can you elaborate on putting this method in the app delegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"My question is: How do I initialize the Second View controller on the same thread.."

You don't need to. If your controllers are in a tab bar controller, then the root controllers of each tab are instantiated at start up. If you need to get reference to it, then use something like self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1]. This will be the controller in the second tab. You do not want to alloc init one, that will create a different instance of SecondView.

Even if you get a correct reference to your secondView, though, what you're trying to do will not work, because secondView's view hasn't loaded yet, so trying to update a label won't work. It isn't clear from your question why you're trying to do this from your first controller since you're not passing anything from it. If this is all you want to do, then just update the label in secondController's viewDidAppear method. If you do want to pass a string from the first view controller, then you should have a string property in secondView, and set the value of that from the first controller. Then, have secondView set the text of its label to that string in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar! To answer your question, the first view controller is setting an NSString value in a Singleton Object and then the Second view Controller is pulling that value out of the same Singleton. I kept my initial question pretty "generic" because I didn't want to add too much detail. I just wasn't entirely sure how to reference other view controllers in a tab bar situation or how the different tab views were instantiated.

I tested out your solution this morning and it worked for me. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `AppDelegate` shouldn't be executing from a different thread, other than the main thread, unless you are creating your own threads, using operations, or attempting UI calls from an asynchronous callback (i.e. asynchronous url request?).

Just curious... can you check whether `myLabel` is nil or not? Another quick check would be to set `myLabel` to a value on the target view controller's init method, rather than wait for the function call.

If you do have other threads and are performing calls to the UI, a good method to switch to the main thread is to use the `NSThread` class, like so:

```
- (void) doSomethingOnUI:(NSString*) label{
   // if the calling thread is not the main thread
   if( ![NSThread isMainThread] )
   {
        // switch to the main thread
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doSomethingOnUI:) 
                               withObject:label 
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
   }

   [self.myLabel setText: label];
}
```